# Jump in running time of repeated splice in WebKit

Tags: javascript, webkit

Running the following in the WebKit console (in Chrome or Safari) takes ~200ms. Running the same code with numbers smaller than 50855, you get what appears to be an approximately linear O(*n*) running time. (For example, with 1e4 you get ~40ms.)

However, change that to 50856 — just an increment by 1 — and there's a huge jump in the running time (to ~600ms on my 13-inch Al MBP, more like ~2s on an old Debian machine). Thereafter, running time appears to be exponential O(2<sup>*n*</sup>): doubling from 50856 to 1e5 yields ~2s on the Mac, which is about a 3.2-fold increase from ~600ms, and doubling again to 2e6 yields a ~10-fold increase. (Note that 3.2<sup>2</sup> ≈ 10.)

In the Opera Dragonfly and in the Firebug consoles, the running time is pretty clearly quadratic O(*n*<sup>2</sup>), as expected (since this splices *n* times where each splice involves shifting *n* items in the array).

...what is WebKit doing?

```
var start = +new Date, a = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 50855; i++)
  a[i] = i;
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  a.splice(i--, 1);
+new Date - start
```

If you don't feel like using the console: http://jsfiddle.net/CVgSt/ Same behavior, though in WebKit the constant factors are a few times smaller than in the console.